# Group generated by $(12)(34)$ and $(24).$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

I am attempting to solve questions on groups akin to:

> Let $a=(12)(34)$ and $b=(24)$ elements of symmetric group $S_4.$ Subgroup $G=\langle a,b\rangle$ generated by $a,b$ is isomorphic to ? Choices are
>
> a) Dihedral group of order $4$
>
> b) Dihedral group of order $8$
>
> c) $S_3$
>
> d) $A_4$

My attempt: $a^2=b^2=(ab)^4=1$; So,

- it can't be a) since a) is generated by $a^4=1, b^2=1$.
- It can't be b) since $D_8$ is generated by $a^8=1, b^2=1$;
- It can't be c) since there is an element of order $4.$
- And it can't be d) since $ab$ is an odd permutation.

What am I missing here?

Also another example:
Let $D_{32}=\langle r,s\mid r^{16}=s^2=1,rs=sr^{−1}\rangle$ and $H=\langle r^9,s \rangle$ is subgroup of $D_{32}$. Then $H$ is isomorphic to ?
Can somebody give me a hint as to how to go about solving problems of this type?

Comment: Your arguments for c) and d) are valid. For a) and b) - group can have different set of generators. For example, any Dihedral group of even order is generated by two elements of order 2.

Comment: $(1 2)(3 4)\cdot (2 4)= (1 2 3 4)$

Comment: This has nothing to do with `free groups`. Please use appropriate tags.

Comment: @mihaild The validity of the argument for d) is not so clear. *A priori*, $G$ could be isomorphic to $A_4$ without being equal to it.

Comment: @José I cannot see the point of your comment.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3614294)

Comment: The dihedral group of order $8$ has no elements of order $8$.

Comment: @AnneBauval with the cycle and the transposition you can generate $D_4$

Comment: I agree with @RobertShore's comment but I cannot see where it is useful.

Comment: @AnneBauval true, my mistake, d) is also not clear.

Comment: This is combinatorial group theory.